# QOpenGLTexture::allocateStorage causes GL_INVALID_VALUE error

Tags: qt, opengl, textures

I've distilled this to trivial Qt code in which the only interesting thing is several lines in `synchronize()` handling a texture. I get a GL_INVALID_VALUE from the `allocateStorage` line. Anyone knows why? I suspect it's probably due to the parameters I pass to this function.

My code:

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickFramebufferObject>
#include <QOpenGLFramebufferObject>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLTexture>

class MyItem : public QQuickFramebufferObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Renderer* createRenderer() const;
};

class MyItemRenderer : public QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer, protected QOpenGLFunctions {
public:
    MyItemRenderer() {
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    }

    void render() {
    }

    QOpenGLFramebufferObject* createFramebufferObject(const QSize &size) {
        QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat format;
        format.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);
        return new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(size, format);
    }

protected:
    void synchronize(QQuickFramebufferObject* qqfbo) {
        Q_UNUSED(qqfbo)

        QOpenGLTexture tex(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
        tex.setSize(100, 100);
        tex.allocateStorage(QOpenGLTexture::BGRA, QOpenGLTexture::Int8);

        qDebug() << "starting loop";
        GLenum err;
        while ((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            qDebug("\tgl error: 0x%x", err, 0, 16);
        }
    }
};

QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer* MyItem::createRenderer() const {
    return new MyItemRenderer();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<MyItem>("MyItem", 1, 0, "MyItem");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

*main.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import MyItem 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    MyItem {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the source of `QOpenGLTexture::createMutableTexture` and `QOpenGLTexture::allocateStorage()` (no-argument version) I saw that two-argument `allocateStorage` overload is really, *really* misleading. The docs make it seem like its 2 args will be used as the **internal format** of the texture (3rd arg of the `glTexImage2D` call in the implementation), when in fact they're used only as the "source-data-to-transfer-from-system-RAM" format/type (7th and 8th args of `glTexImage2D`), which, in the case of passing a null pointer to `glTexImage2D`, don't matter at all except in fringe OpenGL ES 2 cases.

The way to *actually* request a certain **internal format** for the texture is to call `tex.setFormat` before calling `tex.allocateStorage`. So I replaced my `allocateStorage` line with this:

```
tex.setFormat(QOpenGLTexture::RGBA8_UNorm);
tex.allocateStorage();
```

And that fixed the error.

Comment: Well, to also hear the other bell, the two enum types of the parameters of `allocateStorage` clearly document that they're about the external format, not the internal one...

Comment: Qt's GL wrappers are disaster.+1 for the answer,Otherwise I would proably spend hours to figure it out.People who designed this API don't really know OpenGL :/

Answer (score 0):

You have...

```
QOpenGLTexture tex(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
```

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopengltexture.html#QOpenGLTexture) that doesn't actually create the underlying texture object.  I think you then need...

```
tex.create();
```

before setting the size and allocating storage.  So...

```
QOpenGLTexture tex(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
if (!tex.create()) {

  /*
   * Take appropriate action.
   */
}
tex.setSize(100, 100);
tex.allocateStorage(QOpenGLTexture::BGRA, QOpenGLTexture::Int8);
```

**Edit 1**:

Actually, looking at the code it appears that `tex.allocateStorage` should allocate a texture id if necessary.  However, if that fails for some reason (no current context for example) then that could be causing the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks, but I printed `tex.isCreated()` after the `allocateStorage` and I get `true`.

Answer (score 0):

During "allocatestorage", You are conveying opeGL driver about the texture storage format.

For the formats "GL_BGRA or GL_RGBA", OpenGL recommends "GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE",

which is in Qt ----- "`QOpenGLTexture::BGRA`" (for GL_BGRA) and "`QOpenGLTexture::UInt8`" (for GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE).

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Textures_-_more

So your allocate storage function based on (openGL recommendation) should be

```
tex.allocateStorage(QOpenGLTexture::BGRA, QOpenGLTexture::UInt8);
```